# .htaccess How to solve redirection with ignore

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to solve this issue in my .htaccess

I want to redirect all urls that match eg. `/2017/02/some-slug` to `/some-slug`

BUT I want to ignore URLs like this `/2017/02/page/3`

I've managed how to do the first part:

`RewriteRule ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([a-z0-9-\/]+)$ /$3 [R=301,L]`

I have problems with the second part which is ignore. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead in your regex pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^/?\d{4}/\d{2}/(?!page/\d+/?$)(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]
```

Here `(?!page/3/?$)` is negative lookahead that asserts failure when `year/month/` is followed by `page/3`.

Comment: I'm almost there. When I put this: `RewriteRule ^/?\d{4}/\d{2}/(?!(page/([0-9]+)/?)$)(.+)$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,NE]` and try to enter `/2017/12/page/2` it redirects me to `/page/2`

Comment: I tested your rule on my Apache and `http://localhost/2017/02/page/2` doesn't get redirected. Make sure to keep this rule as 1st rule and clear your browser cache completely.

Comment: True, my mistake! Thanks for your help!